# Is the '之' in '要之何用' also regarded as a possessive article?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm confused. Does this '要之何用' mean 'Is there any use?', or could the '之' in this phrase be regarded as a possessive article and therefore the phrase would mean 'What is the use (for someone)'? Or did I get both of them wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 之 following a **noun** is a **possessive marker**
>
> 之 following a **verb**  '要'(have) here is a **pronoun** for 'it'

More examples of 之 as a pronoun when it follows a verb:

- 叫他进来然后**杀**(之) - ask him to come in and then **kill** (him)
- 没有酒就以水**代**(之) - If there's no wine, use water to **substitute** (it)

> 要(钱)何用? = having (money) for what use?
>
> 要(之)何用? = having (it) for what use?
>
> '之' is the pronoun for 'money'

Comment: Is it awkward or not correct to use `为` here, such that `要之为何用`? Because in English `for` is needed, so it sounds more natural for me...

Comment: "要之何用" is a classical style phrase. In modern Chinese, it would be "要(他/它/这个) 来有什么用"  - "要之何用" can be extended to  "要之有何用处" but it would be a mix of classical and  modern style.